# Django update model fields after a certain time

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Assignment model, which has the following attributes for now: title (char Field), deadline(date and time field), closed (boolean field). The closed field denotes if the assignment is past deadline or not. The closed field is false by default.
So now, what I want is that, when an object of the model is created the closed field should be updated automatically on the basis of the deadline. Say the deadline is after 2 hours. Then the closed field should become true after 2 hours. What is the best way to do this? Does Django provide any field of this type; which would update itself after a certain time?

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't support any such fields.
So, here are some options you have

1. create a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)  and run it periodically with a cron job
2. Same can be done with celery [periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)
3. this might not work for wvery case, but can be used if is suitable,
   You can update the status whenever its accessed, so before returning the status check if its true, if true then check if its expired, if expired, set False and return

Answer (score 0):

Don't make closed a field. Make it a computed property - then everything works automatically:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

def two_hours_from_now():
    return timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=2*3600)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=two_hours_from_now)
    ... # other fields, no closed field

    @property
    def closed(self) -> bool:
        return timezone.now() < self.deadline
```